"Error in Flutter Android Build: :path_provider_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac Fails Due to JDK Image Transformation Issue"
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /home/holberton/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
> Error while executing process /opt/android-studio/jbr/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /home/holberton/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /home/holberton/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (1).
Environment:
Flutter version: 3.13.0
Android Studio version: 2023.1.1
Android SDK version: 34
Gradle version: 7.5
JDK version: 11
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04

What I've Tried:
Update Android SDK: I made sure that my Android SDK is up to date, specifically the Android 34 platform.
Clear Gradle and Flutter cache:
    Ran flutter clean to remove any previous build artifacts.
    Cleared the Gradle cache with ./gradlew cleanBuildCache.
Update dependencies:
    Ensured I am using the latest version of the path_provider_android package in my pubspec.yaml.
Check JDK: Verified that JAVA_HOME is set to JDK 11, which is compatible with the Android SDK.
Rebuild the project: After cleaning, I tried rebuilding the project, but the error persists.
Run with stacktrace: I ran the build command with --stacktrace but haven't been able to identify a solution from the logs.

What I Need Help With:
Can anyone explain why the core-for-system-modules.jar transformation is failing?
Is this error related to a mismatch between the Android SDK and the JDK version, or is it specific to the path_provider_android package?
What additional steps should I take to resolve this issue and successfully build the project?

Additional Information:
I am able to build and run other Android projects, but this issue only occurs with this specific Flutter project.
The error seems related to the jlink process and transforming JDK system modules.


In both Android and iOS have path provider problem. I am using Android iguana because of this problem. you can use this configurations for better compiling in android
https://stackoverflow.com/a/79253943/7164993
